# If Page is typeof custom class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to work out whether my webforms `Page` is a certain type.

I've got a number of base classes that inherit one another:

```
BasePage -> System.Web.UI.Page
CMSPage -> BasePage
Page -> CMSPage
```

In a custom `UserControl`, I need to get the the page, but only if it's derived from `CMSPage`.

I've tried:

```
if(Page.GetType() == typeof(CMSPage))
```

But the value of GetType() just returns the class name of the page. It looks like I need to do:

```
if(Page.GetType().BaseType.BaseType == typeof(CMSPage))
```

To get the match working. However, some pages are at different `BaseType` levels before it reaches the type of `CMSPage`.

I could create a function like this to loop through each `BaseType` until it found the right one:

```
public static bool IsPageTypeOf(this System.Web.UI.Page page, Type targetType)
{
    var pageType = page.GetType();
    if (pageType == targetType)
        return true;
    while (pageType.BaseType != null)
    {
        if (pageType.BaseType == targetType)
            return true;
        pageType = pageType.BaseType;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But it feels messy. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
return targetType.IsAssignableFrom(page.GetType());
```

Or if you know the type at compile time:

```
if (page is MyPageType)
```

Or:

```
MyPageType myPage = page as MyPageType;
if (myPage != null)
{
    // Use myPage
}
```

Comment: That last one is my favorite because if I wanted to do something with it I've already got a strongly-typed reference ready to go

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've tried `page is MyPageType` and the `MyPageType myPage = page as MyPageType` but it kept returning `myPage` as not `null`, even on pages that didn't derive from `MyPageType`. `if (typeof(CMSPage).IsAssignableFrom(Page.GetType()))` worked a treat though! I also just came across this: `if (Page.IsPageTypeOf(typeof(CMSPage)))` both work, not sure if there's much difference between them.

Comment: @Scrooby: You've got something wrong then, because `as` certainly *will* work. It can't possibly give a non-null result for a reference to an object which isn't of the right type - it would violate type safety.

Comment: Ah spot on. I'd got my `System.Web.UI.Page` to derived from `CMSPage` by mistake, causing the type confusion. Thanks!